# Getting zip codes from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-code

Does the Google Maps API allow me to get all of the zip codes of a city/state?  For example can I use it to ask the question what zip codes are in San Francisco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible. Although it may be technically possible, Google wouldn't allow it.

The Google Maps API is strict about how you use its service, and how often you can send requests to it. Take a look here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12