# Can I get all the zip codes from a country from Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps

I was wondering if it was possible to get all the existing zip code from a country (let's say Belgium) using the Google Maps API?

Comment: Well, if it's just for Belgium, it's easy to find lists.  Like here http://www.postcodezoeker.be/Postcodes.php . I have them in SQL format (shout if you need them...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [Getting zip codes from Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799793/getting-zip-codes-from-google-maps?rq=1), this could be achieved technically by looping over all possible combinations (i.e. from 1000 to 9999 for Belgium) using the Geocoding API.

That said, Google Maps Geocoding API is not a postal code verification service and you may run into issues trusting it blindly.

There are many other sources out there that can provide you with a list of postal codes.
http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/
https://www.aggdata.com/free/belgium-postal-codes